# Как создать окно на чистом Си используя только стандартную библиотеку по стандарту?

Tags: c++, c

Всем добрый день. Как можно создать свое окно на голом Си? Возможность такая должна быль, поскольку все сторонние библиотеки с графикой написаны именно на Си. Про windows.h и другие инструменты не писать, хочу своими руками попробовать сделать это.

Comment: Никак. Нет такого понятия в стандартной библиотеке С++.

Comment: Все сторонние библиотеки, да и стандартная библиотека тоже, задействуют системеные API, в т.ч. из windows.h Никаких средств работы с GUI в стандартной библиотеке нет.

Answer (score 5):

Никак не создать, в стандартной библиотеке нет таких функций и в ближайшее время не будет. Уже было [предложение](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0267r7.pdf) по добавлению 2D-графики в `C++`. Историю предложения и рассуждения, почему ничего вышло, можно почитать [тут](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/89q6wr/sg13_2d_graphics_why_it_failed/).

Comment: Это зависит от того что считать входящим в стандартную либу. Сокеты включаем?

Comment: @avp нет, это не стандартная библиотека

Comment: @avp есть Networking TS из ближайшего

Comment: Да ну? man 3 socket есть, в POSIX все расписано и не стандартно?

Comment: @avp так POSIX это не ISO C стандарт

Comment: @avp спрашивают же *на голом Си*, а не "с использованием любого стандарта"

Comment: если речь о голом Си (вообще без libc), то нужно лишь реализовать syscall (и посмотреть в include какие номера системных вызовов в кокретном \*nix) / Можно все сделать и на bare metal (без ОС), только мороки много. Проще на новый чип все же снала затащить линь, а уже из под него баловаться с окошками

Comment: @avp "Стандартная библиотека [С](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)/[С++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library)" означает набор функций/классов/... из хедеров, описанных в стандартах С/С++. (Хотя это и называется "библиотека", это не обязательно ровно один целый `.a`/`.so`/`.dll` файл.) Если в libc входит что-то еще, не описанное стандартом С, то это "что-то" - уже не часть стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, если рассуждать так, то вы вообще не можете использовать ОС. Тогда остается вариант bare metal (там вы по сути дела будете просто писать-читать данные по некоторым адресам. В конце-концов вам это немного надоест и вы добавите свои библиотеки, реализующие неким образом всем известные абстракции  ОС)

Comment: @avp Не понимаю, где я такое сказал? Я просто сказал, что сокеты из libc не являются частью "стандартной библиотеки", потому что не описаны в стандартах C/C++. Я не говорил, что поэтому их не стоит использовать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, OK. А syscall  является или нет частью вашего стандарта?

Comment: @avp В стандартах C/C++ такого термина нет, насколько я помню. В posix - наверное есть, но это не считается.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, тогда получается, что реализация стандартов в плане взаимодействия с OS выполняется не стандартными средствами, но это никого особо не волнует. Немного двойных стандартов, не кажется?

Comment: @avp, ну так это реализация самих стандартов, их никак по-другому не реализуешь (если это не freestanding).

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если Вы используете консольный ввод-вывод в окно ДОС, то можете создать в нём своё собственное окошко с помощью символов псевдографики. Правда, я так поступал ещё в прошлом тысячелетии примерно так:

```
void Displays::Interface(float snr)
{
int i;
clrscr();
window(10,8,71,19);     /* координаты углов окна в виде
                             кол,стр,кол,стр */
textbackground(BLUE);    /* цвет фона */
textcolor(WHITE);        /* цвет символов */
clrscr();
cprintf("г=============== Моделирование системы связи ===============¬\r\n");
cprintf("¦                     ПАРАМЕТРЫ  КАНАЛА                     ¦\r\n");
cprintf("¦ Объём входного алфавита кода:                             ¦\r\n");
cprintf("¦ Отношение сигнал-шум [дБ]:                                ¦\r\n");
cprintf("¦ Вид Модуляции:                                            ¦\r\n");
cprintf("¦ Код:                                                      ¦\r\n");
cprintf("¦                                                           ¦\r\n");
cprintf("¦                   РЕЗУЛЬТАТ  НАБЛЮДЕНИЯ                   ¦\r\n");
cprintf("¦ Передано символов:                                        ¦\r\n");
cprintf("¦ Поступило ошибок на вход декодера:                        ¦\r\n");
cprintf("¦ Обнаружено ошибок на выходе декодера:                     ¦\r\n");
cprintf("L===========================================================-");
gotoxy(46,3);
cout<<P;
gotoxy(46,4);
cout<<snr;
gotoxy (46,5);
cout<<"ФМ-"<<M;
gotoxy (46,6);
for (i=0;i<=V;i++) cprintf("%X",CoderWeit[i]);
return;
}
```

Этому фрагменту кода более 30 лет и на писан он для окна ДОС ещё в Borland C++ Builder 3.1

Comment: `window(10,8,71,19);` это точно стандартная функция?

Comment: Тут вообще ни одной стандартной функции. (¬‿¬) Окошечки рисовать можно, но на голом `cout`/`printf`...

Comment: Тут все функции из `conio.h`, который не только не был стандартным, но и который сейчас почти искоренили и в современных компиляторах этих функций нет. А ещё псевдографика тогда была лучше - есть же нормальные символы линий, в не вот эти палочки.

Answer (score -1):

В стандартной библиотеки Си нет возможности создавать окна , так как это функции ОС.
Но используя библиотеку [GTK](https://gtk.org/) можно создавать окна на чистом Си.

Answer (score -3):

Например, используя socket API (вполне стандартно находится в libc) организовать взаимодействие с X-window сервером прямо на X-протоколе.

По сути таким образом вы будете делать свою раелизацию библиотеки X11.

---

Если отказаться от пуризма (в смысле, что есть *стандартная библиотека*),
то на практике есть интересный способ (что-то забылся, когда писал ответ, хотя я его как-то реально использовал) -- это запустить **стороннее приложение**, например,
[wish](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/UserCmd/wish.htm) и организовать с ним "диалог" по паре пайпов.

Comment: Я прсто офигиваю от непонимания реальной картины мира участниками нашего сайта

Comment: Мы похоже понимаем под "стандартной библиотекой" разные вещи. Дайте свое определение?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, для меня стандартная библиотека, это то, что описано в manpages в \*nix (ага, от системы к системе они немного отличаются)

Comment: Хмм. [Википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) считает, что: "The C standard library ... specified in the ANSI C standard ... was developed at the same time as the C library POSIX specification, which is a superset of it.". Обычно я как раз в таком значении слышал это слово.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Если говорить в этом русле, то под стандартной библиотекой я бы имел в  в иду [wikipedia:C POSIX library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library) / По крайней мере в ней больше практического смысла / (однако, боюсь мы уже скатились к обсуждению количества чертей на острие иглы)

Comment: @avp, но ведь есть не POSIX-совместимые ОС, в которых реализована стандартная библиотека C.