# Как создать окно на С++? В VS19

Tags: c++

Как создать окно на С++.Я новичок в деле программирования на С++, но в процедурном программирование немного разбираюсь.

Comment: Гм, это не дубль вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1145562/195342 ?...

Comment: Кажется, нет. И язык другой, и IDE указана.... близко, но все же....

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать окно на чистом Си используя только стандартную библиотеку по стандарту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1145562/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%a1%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80)

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке нет ничего для работы с окнами и графикой, то есть одного стандартного способа нет. Нужно выбрать какую-то библиотеку для работы с графикой и использовать ее...

Answer (score 1):

Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1145594/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1-%d0%92-vs19#comment1983463_1145594):

> В стандартной библиотеке нет ничего для работы с окнами и графикой, то есть одного стандартного способа нет. Нужно выбрать какую-то библиотеку для работы с графикой и использовать ее...

См. [Как создать окно на чистом Си используя только стандартную библиотеку по стандарту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1145562/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%A1%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80)